# How do I configure my sys.path variable in linux?

Tags: python, linux, configuration, path

I want to automatically add entries to python's sys.path variable when run by my user in linux.
Is there something I can tweak in my home directory to get it done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The environment variable [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) sets the initial `sys.path` value.

You can set that it your shell initialization script (e.g. `.bashrc` or `.cshrc`)